# What are the limits to the potions a Master Alchemist can make?

Tags: dnd-3e, prestige-class, potions

I found the Master Alchemist prestige class in the 3rd edition book Magic of Faerûn (p. 34-35), whose main shtick is making potions of up to level 9 with full casting progression (without type!).

The first thing that came to my mind while reading this was "So wait, you can use this to put Fireball in a bottle?". So my question is: with full ranks in Master Alchemist, can you? And what about other such spells? Like Finger of Death, or Imprisonment, or Implosion or other such fun stuff. And what about Summon Creature? Could you create yourself pseudo-Pokéballs this way? And I take it that you'd need to use oils instead of potions, because making a Beholder drink a potion of Harm is quite the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **only** thing about potion brewing that master alchemist changes is the highest level of spell you may put in one. All the other limitations on potions are still in effect. For example:

> #### [Brew Potion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#brewPotion)
>
> **Benefit**
>
> You can create a potion of any [...] spell that you know and that targets one or more creatures.
>
> [...] Whoever drinks the potion is the target of the spell.
>
> #### [Creating Potions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/creatingMagicItems.htm#creatingPotions)
>
> Spells with a range of personal cannot be made into potions.
>
> #### [Potions and Oils](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/potionsAndOils.htm)
>
> [A potion or oil] can duplicate the effect of a spell [...] that has a casting time of less than 1 minute.

That first requirement is the big one. An area-effecting spell, like *fireball*, or a spell with an effect, like *summon monster*, is no good: it has to be a targeted spell. Even *finger of death* arguably doesn’t work, since it is Effect: Ray, not a targeted spell.

And even when you do get an effect like these into a potion, all it does is affect the person drinking it.

All that said, the alchemist savant from *Magic of Eberron* can be used to create “spellvials,” throwing weapons that carry spell effects, similar to the ways potions do. One of my favorite characters ever was an artificer 5/alchemist savant 5/master alchemist 10 (with a minor houserule smoothing out incompatibilities between artificer and master alchemist).

Comment: Alright, but would a similar build be possible for a class that is not an Artificer (and without the dragonmarks/house thing if you're not playing in Eberron)?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs Alchemist savant has an official adaptation for playing in not-Eberron, and works equally well for arcane spellcasters as it does for artificers (the requirements and class features are written for either). I just chose artificer because it was fitting. Wizard would be a good choice, for example.

Comment: Where can I find the adaptation for the wizard? The book just contains the suggested rules for non-Eberron settings.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs it's not an adaptation, it's part of the default functionality of the class. The requirements can be satisfied with infusions or spells, and the class advances either as well.

Comment: "3rd level Arcane spells OR Infusions." Once again I fail to read all there's in there... I thought it was just 3rd level Infusions. But yes, I get it now.